# How to redirect single URL in Nginx?

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I'm in the process of reorganizing URL structure.
I need to setup redirect rules for specific URLs - I'm using Nginx.

Basically Something like this:

```
http://example.com/issue1 --> http://example.com/shop/issues/custom_issue_name1
http://example.com/issue2 --> http://example.com/shop/issues/custom_issue_name2
http://example.com/issue3 --> http://example.com/shop/issues/custom_issue_name3
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is it "isse" or "issue" ?! Answers assume "issue"...

Comment: it's Issue, fixed the typo

Answer (score 133, accepted):

Put this in your server directive:

```
location /issue {
   rewrite ^/issue(.*) http://$server_name/shop/issues/custom_issue_name$1 permanent;
 }
```

Or duplicate it:

```
location /issue1 {
   rewrite ^/.* http://$server_name/shop/issues/custom_issue_name1 permanent;
}
location /issue2 {
   rewrite ^.* http://$server_name/shop/issues/custom_issue_name2 permanent;
}
 ...
```

Answer (score 148):

```
location ~ /issue([0-9]+) {
    return 301 http://example.com/shop/issues/custom_isse_name$1;
}
```

Comment: @Cybolic I just tested this on a docker image with the version `1.10.3` and it was fine, could you provide your config file somehow?
You probably are missing something.

Answer (score 37):

If you need to duplicate more than a few redirects, you might consider using a map:

```
# map is outside of server block
map $uri $redirect_uri {
    ~^/issue1/?$    http://example.com/shop/issues/custom_isse_name1;
    ~^/issue2/?$    http://example.com/shop/issues/custom_isse_name2;
    ~^/issue3/?$    http://example.com/shop/issues/custom_isse_name3;
    # ... or put these in an included file
}

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @redirect-map;
}

location @redirect-map {
    if ($redirect_uri) {  # redirect if the variable is defined
        return 301 $redirect_uri;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I came here looking for -- putting these in an included file is an excellent way to replace my .htaccess file full of RewriteRules from apache.

Comment: how would you combine this map approach with an existing location / ... proxy_pass type setup?

Comment: In the `@redirect-map` location you could try `if ($redirect_uri = "") {return 404;}` followed by proxy_pass stuff. Might need a rewrite using `$redirect_uri`.

Comment: This might be needed instead of the 2 `location` blocks depending on your setup. This is for Craft CMS for example. `location ~ ^(.*)$ {
            if ($redirect_uri) {  # redirect if the variable is defined
                return 301 $redirect_uri;
            }
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?p=$uri&$args;
        }`