# Joomla home page redirect with nginx

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, nginx, joomla

I am with Joomla multisites an trying to make a redirection of the first page of the site:

Some thing like:

```
subdomain.mysite.io/  ->  subdomain.mysite.io/yoga
```

I tried to use that solution: [How to redirect single url in nginx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18037716/how-to-redirect-single-url-in-nginx)

```
location / {
   rewrite ^/.* http://$subdomain.mysite.io/yoga permanent;
}
```

But I get conflict with the configuration file... this is my nginx file for the subdomain...

Could someone help me with that issue? I am using friendly rewrite rules!

```
server {

listen 80;
server_name subdomain.mystie.io www.subdomain.mysite.io;
server_name_in_redirect off;

root /home/joomla/mysite;
index index.php index.html index.htm;


# deny running scripts inside writable directories
location ~* /(images|cache|media|logs|tmp)/.*\.(php|pl|py|jsp|asp|sh|cgi)$ {
        return 403;
        error_page 403 /403_error.html;
}

# Support Clean (aka Search Engine Friendly) URLs
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

}

error_page 404 /404.html;
error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
     root /home/workspaces/php/joomla/portal;
}


# caching of files 
location ~* \.(ico|pdf|flv)$ {
        expires 1y;
}

location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|swf|xml|txt|woff)$ {
        expires 14d;
}



location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pick out a single URI, use the `location =` variant. To make the redirect permanent, use a `return 301`. Try:

```
location = / { return 301 $scheme://$host/yoga/; }
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) and [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#return) for details.