# Redirects in NGINX on a Magento site

Tags: nginx, magento-1.9

I have a website that is in Magento, I am looking at doing some url redirects in NGINX. I have a list of the current url and the new urls

How would I do this please?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18038165/1979882

Comment: That is one way, but I have a CSV file with the curret urls and new urls. So I am just trying to see if there is a piece of code that I could use

Comment: in this case I would advice to use ngixn+lua server. https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module This is very simple to implement your scustom behaviour using simple scripts

Comment: use regex in `rewrite `  as wrote in the firth url